# How can I modify an xml string in java

Tags: java, xml

I have an enum which stores numerous xml strings like this

```
enum1("<?xml version='1.0'?><!DOCTYPE FOO><FOO><HEADER><MESSAGE-ID>1</MESSAGE-ID><MESSAGE-TYPE>RQ</MESSAGE-TYPE></HEADER>[...someXMLstructure...]</FOO>")
enum2("<?xml version='1.0'?><!DOCTYPE FOO><FOO><HEADER><MESSAGE-ID>1</MESSAGE-ID><MESSAGE-TYPE>Q</MESSAGE-TYPE></HEADER>[...someOTHERXMLstructure...]</FOO>")
```

the string is accessed via `myEnum.getTag()`

My application takes user input for some of the nodes represented in this string stored as a `Map<String, String>` with the `key` of the `map` being the `element` of the XML doc, and the `value` being the `value`.

Essentially i want to copy the XML from the enum and replace any corresponding elements found in the map, then send this message as a `String` over via some third party, unrelated interface. For example the user could pass in `MESSAGE-ID=3` and `USER-ID=360` so we would find the `MESSAGE-ID` element of the string and replace that, then find `USER-ID` in some unknown generic location and replace that. If `USER-ID` isn't found in the XML, then it is simply discarded.

**EDIT:**
If there is a better way to do this i.e. convert the XML into some data structure and modify this then convert back to string, I'd be happy to hear it, however I couldn't find much on doing this generically in my searches.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Unless you have a good reason for using enums like this, you may want to rethink the design. There are seemingly infinite ways to represent and manipulate XML in Java. Look into JDom, for example. But maybe what you really need is a templating engine, such as Freemarker, or Velocity.

Comment: I'll look into the templating engine. The enum is an old design desicion that I'll look into changing as well thanks.